# Android - ViewPager causes problems with addTextChangeListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I'm having problems with an activity that uses a `ViewPager` that is populated with two `Fragments`. In my project I have one activity RegisterActivity.java and two fragments: FirstFragment.java and SecondFragment.java. When the activity is created, the two fragments are loaded:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    EditText firstName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_register_first_name);

        firstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // Do something...
            }

        });
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
                    return firstFragment;
                case 1:
                    SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
                    return secondFragment;              
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The following code is found in FirstFragment.java:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View firstInterface = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        return firstInterface;
    }
}
```

and SecondFragment.java:

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View secondInterface = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        return secondInterface;
    }
}
```

I can assure you that all imports and such are there as required. When I run the application I get a `NullPointerException` at line 41, which is where the `addTextChangedListener` is declared. From what reading I've done, my guess as to why the error occurs is because `edit_dext_register_first_name` is not part of the layout used in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);`. Despite the fact that it is part of the layout for one of the fragments, the app doesn't know where to look for my `EditText`, hence the `NullPointerException`. I could be wrong though.

I'm struggling to see how I could fix this issue, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the OnTextChangedListener in the fragment that declares the EditText.

Comment: If I add `EditText firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_register_first_name);` before `return firstInterface;` it doesn't identify `findViewById()` as a method.

Comment: It needs to be firstInterface.findViewById(...)